# Reset Struct Variable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I create a struct to store Strings for the project.

Example:

```
struct StringStruct {
     var BUTTON_TITLE: String = "Okay"
     var CANCEL_TITLE: String = "I don't think so"
     var DECLINE_TITLE: String = "No"
     var PROFILE_TABBAR_TITLE: String = "My Profile"
}
```

In the app, I could change these variables at some point.

I am wondering if I could reset all value back to the initial state?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to reset a `StringStruct` variable would be to
assign a new default value:

```
var strings = StringStruct()
strings.DECLINE_TITLE = "Nein"

strings = StringStruct()
```

If you want to do that as a (mutating) function then I would implement
it as

```
struct StringStruct {
    var BUTTON_TITLE: String = "Okay"
    var CANCEL_TITLE: String = "I don't think so"
    var DECLINE_TITLE: String = "No"
    var PROFILE_TABBAR_TITLE: String = "My Profile"

    mutating func reset() {
        self = StringStruct()
    }
}
```

which eliminates the need to repeat all default values.

Comment: Good addition :). Is there something more tricky in Sep 2018 ?

Answer (score 3):

```
struct StringStruct {
     var BUTTON_TITLE: String = "Okay"
     var CANCEL_TITLE: String = "I don't think so"
     var DECLINE_TITLE: String = "No"
     var PROFILE_TABBAR_TITLE: String = "My Profile"

     mutating func reset() {
         BUTTON_TITLE = "Okay"
         CANCEL_TITLE = "I don't think so"
         DECLINE_TITLE = "No"
         PROFILE_TABBAR_TITLE = "My Profile"
     }
}
```

Comment: The reset func needs to be marked as mutating otherwise you'll get a compile error.